# Migrating Linux to new system

Tags: linux, hardware, uuid, migration

I read a couple posts about migrating Linux from one PC to another PC and my understanding is that Linux will just move and work without issue. Based on my changes this should be true.

I am waiting for one part to come in, but, as it stands I am changing from a DDR3 Memory system to a DDR4 system. Which should not be an issue. From an Intel i7 to an AMD R7 GPU. Since they are both x86_64, this again should not be an issue.

However, where I am concerned: I have my drives mounted as such: root '/' is on my SSD, my home '/home' is on my 1TB drive, and a games drive mounted as '/home/Games' that is also a 1TB drive. Now, they are all currently mounted via their UUIDs. Is there any changes I need to make here for migration?

Are there any other changes I should check before Migration?

Manjaro 4.14.12

Comment: Nope, the fact that you are using UUIDs to reference a filesystem means that the changing device (`/dev/sda` on one to `/dev/sdb` on another, etc) won't have an effect on you.  This is what UUIDs are for.

Comment: I thought that, its just good to confirm!